# sum total with the blank cell under in excel/VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I want to sum total figure of quantity by checking with blank cell under. like say invoice A have two figure 1 and 2 so the total show 3. many thanks

[image: Excel]

Comment: What formula have you tried and what is the result you're getting instead of the right result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Logic: Check `Inv`, if it is blank, sum up `Qty`. If not, it means we met a new `Inv`. Therefore, we store the sum into last `Total` and read data for new `Inv`.

```
Private Sub Total()
    With ActiveSheet
        Dim lastRow As Long
        lastRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
        Dim i As Long
        Dim sum As Long
        Dim firstInvCell As Range

        On Error Resume Next
        For i = 2 To lastRow
            If .Cells(i, 1).Value = "" Then
                'Inv is blank, sum up
                sum = sum + .Cells(i, 2).Value
            Else
                'Inv is not blank, means next inv starts from here
                firstInvCell.Value = sum
                'store the first row of this inv
                Set firstInvCell = .Cells(i, 3)
                sum = .Cells(i, 2).Value
            End If
        Next i

        firstInvCell.Value = sum
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple VBA sub do-until with will do, something like this

```
index = 1 ' Initialize row index.
Do Until index > 7 ' Change 7 to .usedrange.Rows.Count / your number of rows.
    If Range("A1").Offset(index - 1, 0).Value <> vbNullString Then
        sum = Range("B1").Offset(index - 1, 0).Value
        position = index + 1
        ' Do a running sum, until encounter the next non-blank
        Do Until Range("A1").Offset(position - 1, 0) <> vbNullString
            sum = sum + Range("B1").Offset(position - 1, 0).Value
            position = position + 1
            If position > 7 Then Exit Do ' Just in case.
        Loop
        Range("C1").Offset(index - 1, 0).Value = sum
        ' Reassign pointer
        index = position
    End If
Loop
```

Comment: ... is it because I jumped the gun and just provide an answer anyway, that I got a downvote? :<